# One method retrieves all the data or few smaller methods retrieve each part?

Tags: php, class, methods, pdo

I have several doubts about OOP PHP code I'm creating. It is (so far) for retrieving a title and several chapters in different languages stored online. But first I will show the code as my doubts refer to this. This is the class I'm currently working with:

```
<?php
// Requires PHP 5.4+
class Subject
  {
  private $DB;
  private $Language;
  private $Keyword;

  public function __construct($DB, $Keyword, $Language)
    {
    $this->DB=$DB;
    $this->Keyword=$Keyword;
    $this->Language=$Language;
    }

  private function query($query, $arg)
    {
    $STH = $this->DB->prepare($query);
    $STH->execute(array_merge((array)$this->Keyword, (array)$arg));
    return $STH->fetch()[$this->Language];  // PHP 5.4+
    }

  public function retrieveTitle ()
    {
    return $this->query("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE keyword = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
    }

  public function retrieveChapter ($arg)
    {
    return $this->query("SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE subject_keyword = ? AND type = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1", $arg);
    }
?>
```

Then I do something similar to this to display the page:

```
if (isset($_GET['a']))
  {
  $Subject=new Subject($DB, $_GET['a'], $User->get('language'));

  if ($Subject->retrieveTitle())
    {
    echo '<h1 id="Title">'.$Subject->retrieveTitle().'</h1>';

    // Index
    if ($Subject->retrieveTitle())
      // ... code for the index

    // Introduction
    if ($Subject->retrieveChapter('Introduction'))
      echo '<h2 id="Introduction">' . $_('Introduction') . '</h2>' . $Subject->retrieveChapter('Introduction');

    // ... more non-relevant code.
    }
  }
else
  // ... whatever
```

**First concern.** I'm not sure if this is the proper way to handle this kind of data. I tried to separate the methods and make them as small as possible, trying also not to repeat much code. And this is the way that *feels* right. But I cannot see why this other code, similar to the previous one, is less desirable. Note: This class has SURELY some typos and has not been tested, it's only here to ilustrate the difference, so please don't use it (at least not literaly):

```
<?php
// Requires PHP 5.4+
class Subject
  {
  public $Title;
  public $Chapters = array ();

  public function __construct($DB, $Keyword, $Language)
    {
    // Retrieve all
    $STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE keyword = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
    $STH->execute(array($Keyword));
    $this->Title = $STH->fetch()[$Language];  // PHP 5.4+

    // Retrieve chapters
    $ToForeach = ('Introduction','History','1');
    $STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE subject_keyword = ? AND type = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
    foreach ($ToForeach as $part)
      {
      $STH->execute(array($Keyword, $part));
      $this->Chapters = $STH->fetch()[$Language];
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

And then access the properties directly (or even build some get() in the middle, but you get the idea).

So, is there any difference? What are the benefits and pitfalls of the first method vs the second to code the class? Memory usage should be slightly smaller in the first one, but I think that won't be a deal breaker in comparison to readability in this case.

EDIT: Just writing the question in a way for others to understand has lead me to think about it in other ways. The first way also looks easier to test.

**Second concern.** If I want to make a/some methods for saving data, should I put it in the same class or in a different one? Because if I put it in one it bundles all the subject related methods in one pretty independent class, if I separate it I have more specialized classes with separated roles.

Any further advice, specifically about coding best practices [that I might not be following], is also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy to answer in a good way. So I can only focus on some minor parts of it. For not repeating code, I'd say the first example you give has quite some repeated code:

```
class Subject
{
    /**
     * @var ParametrizedQueryFetchQueryFactory
     */
    private $queryFactory;

    public function __construct($DB, $Keyword, $Language) {

        $this->queryFactory = new ParametrizedQueryFetchQueryFactory($DB, $Language, [$Keyword]);
    }

    private function query($query, array $args = array()) {
        return $this->queryFactory->query($query, $args);
    }

    public function retrieveTitle() {

        return $this->query("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE keyword = ? ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1");
    }

    public function retrieveChapter($part) {
        return $this->query(
            "SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE subject_keyword = ? AND TYPE = ? ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1",
            [$part]
        );
    }
}

class ParametrizedQueryFetchQueryFactory
{
    private $db, $returnIndex, $defaultArgs;

    public function __construct($db, $returnIndex, array $defaultArgs = array()) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->returnIndex = $returnIndex;
        $this->defaultArgs = $defaultArgs;
    }

    public function query($query, array $args = array()) {
        $fetcher = new ParametrizedQueryFetch($this->db,$query, $this->returnIndex, $this->defaultArgs);
        return $fetcher->execute($args);
    }
}

class ParametrizedQueryFetch
{
    private $db, $query, $returnIndex, $defaultArgs;
    public function __construct($db, $query, $returnIndex, array $defaultArgs = array()) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->query = $query;
        $this->returnIndex = $returnIndex;
        $this->defaultArgs = $defaultArgs;
    }

    public function execute(array $args) {
        $args = array_merge($this->defaultArgs, $args);
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->query);
        $stmt->excute($args);
        return $stmt->fetch()[$this->returnIndex];
    }
}
```

And btw, to make this PHP 5.3 compatible, you would only need to change a single line here.

Comment: I edited my original code to actually avoid repeating code. However, I'm really surprised about how long is your code and actually took a while to understand HOW it works. Now I do, yet I don't know the why. I'm really curious about the benefits that are with your code to justify that it's much longer, so what are they? BTW, thank you for the elaborated answer!

Comment: When you have 1000s of such parametrized SQL queries you execute from within your shell classes that give interface into your code to the data in the database, it can make sense to add something that does the job for that case, e.g. like running these parametrized, partly-preconfigured queries from within classes. That's all. Sure for two functions is too verbose, you could put the code into `private function query()` also from the public functions, too. That was the first step.